# StackedBarChart not updating in FXML app

Tags: java, javafx-2, bar-chart, fxml, scenebuilder

The stacked bar chart not working with FXML and controller class. Please help me. My code is given below

Controller class

```
    /* 
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties. 
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates 
* and open the template in the editor. 
*/  

package javafxapplication27;  

import java.net.URL;  
import java.util.Arrays;  
import java.util.ResourceBundle;  
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;  
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;  
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;  
import javafx.fxml.FXML;  
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;  
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;  
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;  
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;  
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;  
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;  
import javafx.scene.control.Label;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;  


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {  

    @FXML  
    private Label label;  

    @FXML  
    private StackedBarChart stackChart;  

    @FXML  
    private BarChart barChart;  

    @FXML  
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {  
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");  
        label.setText("Hello World!");  

    final  String austria   = "Austria";  
    final  String brazil    = "Brazil";  
    final  String france    = "France";  
    final  String italy     = "Italy";  
    final  String usa       = "USA";  
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();  
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();  
    ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> barChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();  
    ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Number>> stackBarChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();  
    final BarChart.Series<String, Number> series1 =  new BarChart.Series<String, Number>();  
    final StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number> series2 =   new StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number>();  
    final StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number> series3 =   new StackedBarChart.Series<String, Number>();  
        series1.setName("2001");  
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(austria, 25601.34));  
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(brazil, 20148.82));  
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(france, 10000));  
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(italy, 35407.15));  
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(usa, 12000));  
        series2.setName("2004");  
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(austria, 57401.85));  
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(brazil, 41941.19));  
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(france, 45263.37));  
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(italy, 117320.16));  
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(usa, 14845.27));  
        series3.setName("2005");  
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(austria, 45000.65));  
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(brazil, 44835.76));  
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(france, 18722.18));  
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(italy, 17557.31));  
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(usa, 92633.68));      

        barChartData.add(series1);  
        stackBarChartData.addAll(series2,series3);  
        stackChart.setData(stackBarChartData);  
        barChart.setData(barChartData);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {  
        // TODO  
    }     

}
```

FXML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<?import java.lang.*?>  
<?import java.util.*?>  
<?import javafx.scene.*?>  
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>  
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>  
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>  

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="487.0" prefWidth="610.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="javafxapplication27.FXMLDocumentController">  
  <children>  
    <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" />  
    <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="120.0" minHeight="16.0" minWidth="69.0" />  
    <StackedBarChart fx:id="stackChart" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="33.0" prefHeight="223.0" prefWidth="576.0">  
      <xAxis>  
        <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />  
      </xAxis>  
      <yAxis>  
        <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />  
      </yAxis>  
    </StackedBarChart>  
    <BarChart fx:id="barChart" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="264.0" prefHeight="216.0" prefWidth="552.0">  
      <xAxis>  
        <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />  
      </xAxis>  
      <yAxis>  
        <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />  
      </yAxis>  
    </BarChart>  
  </children>  
</AnchorPane>
```

When I run this program, only the barchart populating, Stacked bar chart not displas any graph.

Output window

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from oracle OTN forum , by mr . [bouye](https://community.oracle.com/people/bouye?customTheme=otn)

From the article [Bar Chart at Oracle's](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm), you would need to do:

```
((CategoryAxis)stackChart.getXAxis()).setCategories(FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(austria, brazil, france, italy, usa)));
```

Or more simply:

```
((CategoryAxis)stackChart.getXAxis()).getCategories().setAll(austria, brazil, france, italy, usa);
```

For me it fixes the issue.